# I am trying to find our who has fies checked in, TFS 2012 will not show, even thou I am Admin

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find our who has files checked in, TFS 2012 will not show, even though I am Admin.

`File----> Source Control ----->Find----->Find by status`

Nothing, no items found, even though I checked out few files.

Comment: Do you mean checked **out**? If they are checked in then you'll have to check the history to see who was the last to check in.

Comment: YES Checked out I mean

Answer (score 0):

Try out the SideKicks from http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

These have always been helpful to us.

Comment: Thank You, I do use TFS SideKicks but it does not show what files are checked out